# python urllib: build urls including parameters with and without keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am building grafana links in python with `urllib` like the following:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlunsplit

parameters = {
    "parameter1":"value1",
    "parameter2":"value2"
}

query = urlencode(
    query = parameters,
    doseq = True
)

link = urlunsplit((
    "https",
    "my_grafana.com",
    "/graph",
    query,
    ""
))
```

`link` will be in this case `'https://my_grafana.com/graph?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2'`. I now want to add parameters with no keyword for example "kiosk". The link should look like `'https://my_grafana.com/graph?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&kiosk&other_parameter'`

As `urlencode` returns a string with the parameters I could manipulate the string like in the following example before I give it to `urlunsplit`:

```
no_keyword_parameters = ["kiosk","other_parameter"]
query = "&".join([query, *no_keyword_parameters])
```

I wonder if you can put parameters with and without keyword directly with `urlencode` together. I tried giving "kiosk" as a dictionary entry with `None` as content (`{"kiosk": None}`) but it includes the `None` in the url. Approaches, where I give a list of tuples instead of a dictionary for the parameters, were also unsuccessful.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: maybe graphana can works with empty `kiosk=` and `other_parameter=` - then you could use `{"kiosk": ""}`

Comment: @furas: I tried that, but grafana does not accespt it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done seems sound and you could either do it like that or formalize it a bit more in your own encoding function, but `urllib.parse.urlencode` does not seem to understand the notion of parameters without value. If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L931) (with `doseq` you get a variation of the same for the part relevant to your question):

```
        for k, v in query:
...
           l.append(k + '=' + v)
```

I.e. you have to have a key, value pair (to unpack two values) and whatever they are quoted to (that happens in the ellipses) will be a `str` joined over `=`. So even using custom `qoute_via` you cannot really change its function.

That linked implementation is the one provided with CPython, but also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) expects: key/value pairs, so that behavior really is as specified / documented:

> The resulting string is a series of key=value pairs separated by '&' characters...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Ondrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9288200/ondrej-k), `urlencode` builds the query using `k + '=' + v`.
You could add non value parameters manually:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlunsplit, quote_plus

parameters = {"parameter1": "value1", "parameter2": "value2"}
no_value_parameters = ["kiosk", "other_parameter"]
no_value_parameters_quoted = [quote_plus(p) for p in no_value_parameters]

query = urlencode(query=parameters, doseq=True)
link = urlunsplit(("https", "my_grafana.com", "/graph", query, ""))
link = f"{link}&{'&'.join(no_value_parameters_quoted)}"
print(link)
```

Out:

```
https://my_grafana.com/graph?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&kiosk&other_parameter
```